# How do I bind input fields in fluxible react.js

Tags: reactjs, fluxible

How do I bind input fields in fluxible react.js?  Looking at the example apps for todo, they bind an onchange event on the input box and bind that to an onchange method.  Doing the same technique for multiple fields seems tedious - having a separate method and event handler for every field.  Is there a way to just get the values from the input boxes on submit?  Should I be storing the field values in state?

```
import React from 'react';
import registerUser from '../actions/registerUser';

class Register extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username:'',
            password:'',
            email:'',
            errorMessage:null
        };
        //this.state = this.getStoreState();
    }


    register = (event, value) => {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        console.log(value);
        let username = this.state.username.trim();
        let password = this.state.password.trim();
        let email = this.state.email.trim();

        if (username && password && email) {
            this.context.executeAction(registerUser, {
                username: username,
                password: password,
                email: email
            });
        } else {
            this.state.errorMessage = "missing required fields"
        }
        this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    };

    //todo handle error and success
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.errorMessage}
                <form className="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Register</legend>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        <button onClick={this.register} type="submit" className="pure-button pure-button-primary">Sign Up</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: You could bind all the fields to the same change method, adding a parameter on which field to update. Then in set state set state[field] based on that param.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component for the input like so.

```js
import React from 'react';

import Actions from './../flux/Actions';
import JInput from './common/jInput';

import BasicStore from './../flux/Basic.Store';

let AppCtrlSty = {
 height: '100%',
 padding: '0 10px 0 0'
}

let checkBoxSty = {
 boxSizing: 'border-box',
 display: 'inline-block',
 lineHeight: '18px',
 marginLeft: '2px',
 outline: 'none',
 position: 'relative'
};

let radioSty = {color: "blue"}

let input3Sty = {color: 'green'};

let inputLabel = {margin: '0 5px'};

let textInput1 = {name: 'text', type: 'text', textValue: '', focus: true};
let checkInput1 = {name: 'checkbox', type: 'checkbox', style: checkBoxSty};
let colorInput = {name: 'color', type: 'color'};
let numberInput = {name: 'number', type: 'number', min: 0, max: 100};
let rangeInput = {name: 'range', type: 'range', min: 0, max: 100};

let radioInput1 = {name: 'radioGroup', type: 'radio', radioValue: 'set'};
let radioInput2 = {name: 'radioGroup', type: 'radio', radioValue: 'setkey'};
let radioInput3 = {name: 'radioGroup', type: 'radio', radioValue: 'key'};

class AppCtrlRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
   let inputData = this.state.data;

  textInput1.textValue = inputData.text;
  checkInput1.checkedValue = inputData.checkbox;
  colorInput.colorValue = inputData.color;
  numberInput.numberValue = inputData.number;
  rangeInput.numberValue = inputData.range;

  let currentRadioGroupValue = this.state.data.radioGroup;
  radioInput1.radioChecked = (currentRadioGroupValue == radioInput1.radioValue);
  radioInput2.radioChecked = (currentRadioGroupValue == radioInput2.radioValue);
  radioInput3.radioChecked = (currentRadioGroupValue == radioInput3.radioValue);

  let selected = inputData.checkbox ? 'true' : 'false';
  let radioGroupName1 = 'key1'; //must be distinct for each use of JRadioGroup
  let radioValue = inputData.radioGroup;
  return (
   <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
    React 1.4 Form input<br/><br/>
    Text: <JInput input={textInput1} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /><br/><br/>
    Checkbox: <JInput input={checkInput1} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Value: {selected}<br/><br/>
    Color: <JInput input={colorInput} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Value: {colorInput.colorValue}<br/><br/>
    Number: <JInput input={numberInput} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Value: {numberInput.numberValue}<br/><br/>
    Range: <JInput input={rangeInput} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} /> Value: {rangeInput.numberValue}<br/><br/>

    Radio Input: &nbsp;
    <JInput input={radioInput1} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} />&nbsp;Set &nbsp;
    <JInput input={radioInput2} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} />&nbsp;Set/Key &nbsp;
    <JInput input={radioInput3} handleChange={this.handleValueChange} />&nbsp;Key &nbsp;
    Value: {radioValue}
   </div>
  );
 }
}

function getState() { return {data: BasicStore.getData()}; };

export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
 constructor() {
   super();
  this.state = getState();
 }

 componentDidMount() { this.unsubscribe = BasicStore.listen(this.storeDidChange); }
 componentWillUnmount() { this.unsubscribe(); }

 storeDidChange = () => { this.setState(getState()); }
 handleValueChange = (name, value) => { Actions.editRecord(name, value); }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';

class JInputRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
  let inputSty = this.props.input.style ? this.props.input.style : {color: 'red'};
  let textValue = this.state.textValue;
  let colorValue = this.props.input.colorValue ? this.props.input.colorValue : '#1A3212';
  let checkedValue = (this.props.input.checkedValue != null) ? this.props.input.checkedValue : false;
  let numberValue = this.props.input.numberValue ? this.props.input.numberValue : 0;
  let radioValue = this.props.input.radioValue ? this.props.input.radioValue : '';
  let radioChecked = (this.props.input.radioChecked != null) ? this.props.input.radioChecked : false;
  let min = this.props.input.min ? this.props.input.min : 0;
  let max = this.props.input.max ? this.props.input.max : 100;
  let step = this.props.input.step ? this.props.input.step : 1;
  let inputType = this.props.input.type ? this.props.input.type : 'text';

  let returnRadio = (
    <input
     ref="inputRef"
     type={inputType}
     style={inputSty}
     checked={radioChecked}
     value={radioValue}
     onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
   )

  let returnChecked = (
    <input
     ref="inputRef"
     type={inputType}
     style={inputSty}
     checked={checkedValue}
     onChange={this.handleCheckedChange} />
   )

  let returnColor = (
    <input
     type={inputType}
     ref="inputRef"
     style={inputSty}
     value={colorValue}
     onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
   )

  let returnNumber = (
    <input
     type={inputType}
     ref="inputRef"
     style={inputSty}
     value={numberValue}
     min={min} max={max} step={step}
     onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
   )

  let returnText = (
    <input
     type={inputType}
     ref="inputRef"
     style={inputSty}
     value={textValue}
     onChange={this.handleTextValueChange} />
   )
  let returnIt = {};
  switch (inputType) {
   case 'checkbox': returnIt = returnChecked; break;
   case 'radio': returnIt = returnRadio; break;
   case 'color': returnIt = returnColor; break;
   case 'number':
   case 'range': returnIt = returnNumber; break;
   default: returnIt = returnText; break;
  }

  return (returnIt);
 }
}

export default class JInput extends JInputRender {
 constructor() {
   super();
  this.state = {textValue: ''};
 }

 componentDidMount = () => {
  if (this.props.input.textValue) this.setState({textValue: this.props.input.textValue});
  if (this.props.input.focus) this.refs.inputRef.focus();
 }
 componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
  if (nextProps.input.textValue && (this.state.textValue != nextProps.input.textValue))
   {this.setState({textValue: nextProps.input.textValue});}
 }

 handleCheckedChange = (event) => { this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, event.target.checked); }
 handleTextValueChange = (event) => {
  let newValue = event.target.value;
  this.setState({textValue: newValue});
  this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, newValue);
 }
 handleValueChange = (event) => { this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, event.target.value); }
}
```